# How to customize the_content() on Wordpress for the homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, customization

I'm trying to customize a wordpress home page, exactly, the_content() function.
the website I'm trying to use is http://sportsponsorizzazioni.com/

If in the file about "loop" I use the function "**the_content()**" it gives me a list of full articles on the home page, *with* the image I've included in the post body and the text formatted as I want.
Using the function "the_excerpt()" in an other way, show me only the excerpt text, like 5 rows, *without* any image.

I just want to display on my home page, the first part of an article, with "read more" button after, and the image, but then I do a substring operation on the_content(''), it only gives me first X characters but without image... even if in my post the tag  is on the start of the post.

I need something automatic, can't add a "thumbnail image" or a "featured image" on every single post, is there a way to modify "the_content('')" to let me take for example only the first 30 words of my post with the image?
Or (better) is there a way to include in "the_excerpt()" the image coded in my article?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you search through the thousands of wordpress plug-ins out that that do various forms of display modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) does exactly what you're trying to do. See [item number 4](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/faq/) in the FAQ section for pulling images from post content.

Comment: That's it! exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to go to the plugin solution,
1. add custom field to posts, for example with name of post-image and value of image url(try to use the custom field for all posts).
2. include a code similar to below in your home.php

```
<?php if(have_post()):

  while(have_post()):
   the_post(); ?>

   <div id="<?php the_ID();?>" <?php post_class();?>>
      <!--output the excerpt-->
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <!--access the image source as below-->
         <?php $img_src=get_post_meta($post->ID,'post-image',$single=true); ?>

          <!--check if $img_src is not empty, in case there will be 
          a post without post-image custom field.
          -->
          <?php if($img_src !==''): ?>
          <img src="<?php $img_src;?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"      class="home_image" />
                        <?php endif;?>
                          <!--whenever there is a post with no image, you may like 
                             to add else logic here and do something-->
     </div>

   <?php endwhile; else: ?>

   <!--some error message-->

   <?php endif; ?>
```