# How to change results content in search.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello Wordpress People,

I wanted to ask how I can change the output for my search results in the code below the part `<div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>`?

I want only to show the Page, Post or Category Title and the Text. But Text also only like 500 Charaters to show and then a link "read more".

Is there a way to get this done? Thanks for any help.

This is my code for search.php:

```
<div id="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <p class="info">Ihre Suchergebnisse f&uuml;r: <strong><?php echo $s ?></strong></p>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <p align="center"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; &Auml;ltere Eintr&auml;ge') ?> | <?php previous_posts_link('Neuere Eintr&auml;ge &raquo;') ?></p>

    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="no-found">
            <h3>Ups?! Wir konnten unter dem Begriff <span>"<?php echo $s ?>"</span> leider nichts finden.</h3>
            <p>Kehren Sie bitte <a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>">zur Startseite</a> zurück.</p>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- main -->

<div id="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- sidebar -->
```

Comment: Have you looked to see if this question has been asked before? Such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595544/how-to-customize-the-content-on-wordpress-for-the-homepage?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just change `the_content()` to `the_excerpt()` instead. This will get you pretty close to what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the_excerpt() function instant of the_content and use a link with read more(permalink).

Here the code :

```
<div class="entry">
         <?php the_excert(); ?> 
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
        </div>
```

also, you can follow this Question and answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70913/how-can-i-limit-the-character-length-in-excerpt)

Thanks